# Why is Linkedin Ugc Image Post Returning a 500 error?

Tags: php, curl, linkedin-api, php-curl

I'm working on making an Image Share with the LinkedIn v2 api. There are three steps, according to [the LinkedIn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin#create-an-image-share).

1. Register your image to be uploaded.
2. Upload your image to LinkedIn.
3. Create the image share.

I got past the first two using php curl, but I'm stuck on the third.
Step 3, which is done with a ugcPost.

Here are is the post body I sent to the ugc endpoint:

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:person:{id-redacted}",
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED",
    "specificContent": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.ShareContent": {
            "shareCommentary": {
                "text": "hello"
            },
            "shareMediaCategory": "IMAGE",
            "media": {
                "stats": "READY",
                "description": {
                    "text": "this is a descriptoin"
                },
                "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:{id-redacted}",
                "title": {
                    "text": "this is some title text"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "visibility": {
        "com.linkedin.ugc.MemberNetworkVisibility": "PUBLIC"
    }
}
```

Here is the code i used to send curl post request with php:

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $ugcPostEndpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json","X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0"));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));
```

returns this from curl:

```
 Hostname was found in DNS cache
   Trying 108.174.10.12...
 Connected to api.linkedin.com (108.174.10.12) port 443 (#2)
 successfully set certificate verify locations:
   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
 SSL connection using {redacted}
 Server certificate:
        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=Mountain View; O=LinkedIn Corporation; CN=tablet.linkedin.com
        start date: 2018-03-30 00:00:00 GMT
        expire date: 2020-04-27 12:00:00 GMT
        subjectAltName: api.linkedin.com matched
        issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
        SSL certificate verify ok.
 POST /v2/ugcPosts?oauth2_access_token={redacted} HTTP/1.1
Host: api.linkedin.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type:application/json
X-Restli-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
Content-Length: 734

 upload completely sent off: 734 out of 734 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error
< X-LI-ResponseOrigin: RGW
< Content-Type: application/json
< X-RestLi-Error-Response: true
< X-Restli-Gateway-Error: false
< X-RestLi-Protocol-Version: 2.0.0
< X-Li-Fabric: prod-ltx1
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-Li-Pop: prod-edc2
< X-LI-Proto: http/1.1
< X-LI-UUID: {redacted}
< Set-Cookie: {redacted}
< X-LI-Route-Key: {redacted}
<
 Connection #2 to host api.linkedin.com left intact
```

Why is this 500 error occuring? As far as I know I am following all of the examples/docs. (I know that 500 errors could be a problem on their end but in my experience when dealing with APIs 500 errors often mean that the curl request is wrong somehow.

Comment: Are you adding the OAuth 2.0 access token to the `Authorization` header?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what I was doing wrong in case anyone else has a similar issue.

The media part of the body has to be the 0th element in an array like this:

```
 "media": [
            {
                "status": "READY",
                "description": {
                    "text": "this is a description"
                },
                "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:{id}",
                "title": {
                    "text": "this is some title text"
                }
            }
        ]
```

Not this:

```
     "media":
            {
                "status": "READY",
                "description": {
                    "text": "this is a description"
                },
                "media": "urn:li:digitalmediaAsset:{id}",
                "title": {
                    "text": "this is some title text"
                }
            }
```

The LinkedIn docs don't make this super obvious.